# Extend double vertical bar

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

I'm trying to write an expression in math mode similar to this formula:

[image]

My LaTeX expression looks like this:

```
\min \| \begin{array}{c} ... \end{array} \|
```

but it happens that the double lines are short:

[image]

How can I extend the double vertical bar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `\left ... \right` construction. See page 60 and table 3.8 of the [Not so short intro. to LaTeX](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) for further details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\min \left\| \begin{bmatrix} A\\ \vdots \\ C\end{bmatrix} \right\|
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does one do if one doesn't need the corresponding `\left` delimiter? LaTeX complains if it is not present.

Comment: What worked for me was to use "\left." on the LHS of the expression and the "\right\rvert" on the RHS. Tony Rollett