# Doubled parentheses, braces, brackets and angles

Tags: delimiters, mathtools, parentheses

I need some doubled versions of the standard parentheses, namely parentheses, braces, brackets and angles. They should be scalable and the output should look *roughly* like this:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\left\lbrack\!\left\lbrack a\right\rbrack\!\right\rbrack$
$\left\lbrack\!\!\left\lbrack \frac12\right\rbrack\!\!\right\rbrack$
$\left\lbrack\!\!\left\lbrack \dfrac{1}{2}\right\rbrack\!\!\right\rbrack$

$\left\lbrace\!\!\left\lbrace a\right\rbrace\!\!\right\rbrace$
$\left\lbrace\!\!\left\lbrace \frac12\right\rbrace\!\!\right\rbrace$
$\left\lbrace\!\!\!\left\lbrace \dfrac{1}{2}\right\rbrace\!\!\!\right\rbrace$

\end{document}
```

For example, the package `stmaryrd` provides the commands `\llbracket` resp. `\rrbracket` for doubled brackets. However I have some compatability issues with this package and also, the other delimiters are missing. Finally, I would like to be able to turn my symbols into Delimiters using the `mathtools` functionality. How can I achieve all this?

Edit: Bernard found a package providing doubled brackets and doubled angles (thanks for this!) but I am still interested in the other symbols.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `mathabx`  provides`\ldbracket` (alias `\semantic`)and `\rdbracket` (`\rsemantic`). `MnSymbol` has `\lsem`, `\rsem`, `\llangle`, `rrangle`.

Comment: the `stmaryrd` package might help.  Also, this is related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100966/defining-scalable-white-curly-brackets-and-and

Comment: If you are prepared to use lua or xe latex, then unicode math provides most of these depending the font chosen.  See `unimath-symbols` at http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf for the coverage.

Comment: @andrewswann actually I did not know a thing such as lua latex existed. I tried it out now and whilst breaking some parts of my document, the usage of  `unimath-symbols` basically works. However the commands `\lBrace` and `\rBrace` don't work and neither does the scaling of e.g. `\lAngle` and `\rAngle` using `\big` or `\left`. Any Ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Pure guess, you have written something like `\setmathfont{xits}` instead of `\setmathfont{xits math}`.  Otherwise please edit your question to show the code you have tried.

Comment: If the answer below fits your needs, consider to upvote **and** accept  it please in order to show your appreciation of Andrew Swann's work done to help you.

Comment: Duplicate of [`[]` and `()`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107252/double-square-brackets?noredirect=1&lq=1) • [`{}` (pdflatex only, no Unicode)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100966/defining-scalable-white-curly-brackets-and-and?noredirect=1&lq=1) • [`<>`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12464/extensible-double-angle-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1). Unrelated, but there's also [`||`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57945/extend-double-vertical-bar?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

If you are prepared to use lualatex or xelatex then you can use `unicode-math`.  Several of the fonts there provide the brackets you ask for including the XITS font.

[image: Sample output]

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math,mathtools}
\setmainfont{xits}
\setmathfont{xits math}

\begin{document}

$\left\lBrack a \right\rBrack$
$\left\lBrack \frac12 \right\rBrack$
$\left\lBrack \dfrac{1}{2}\right\rBrack$

$\left\lBrace a \right\rBrace$
$\left\lBrace \frac12 \right\rBrace$
$\left\lBrace \dfrac{1}{2} \right\rBrace$

$\left\lParen a \right\rParen$
$\left\lParen \frac12 \right\rParen$
$\left\lParen \dfrac{1}{2} \right\rParen$

$\left\lAngle a \right\rAngle$
$\left\lAngle \frac12 \right\rAngle$
$\left\lAngle \dfrac{1}{2} \right\rAngle$

\end{document}
```